# Easy way to play a "B" chord on guitar

Tags: guitar, learning

I learned to play guitar a couple years ago, but I can't for the life of me play a "B" chord.  Is there any version that isn't a bar chord?  Or do I have to suck it up and learn to play a bar chord?

Comment: If you need that chord while you're in key E, then B7 is the answer. X21202. Otherwise, there is only the 'A' shape barre on fret 2, or the 'E' shape barre on fret 7. Since you want to play guitar, learning barre chords has to be the way to go. Like it, lump it, do it !

Comment: Thank you!  That really helps.  I probably will learn the B chord at some point.

Comment: Trying to play the B with a barre on the 2nd fret and fingers 2,3 and 4 on the 4th fret is tough for a beginner. Try playing the low B on fret 2 string 5 with your index finger and using your pinky as a barre on the 4 high strings. You can support it with your ring finger. Just avoid picking or plucking the high E string since that note is not part of a regular B chord.

Comment: If you mute you don’t have to barre the E shape. You can play it X9987X

Comment: @JohnBelzaguy I disapprove of these fingerings, especially for beginners, because they only really work in a “thumb around the neck” position – not a good habit to get into. (Not to say it can't sometimes be a useful tool to _also_ have available, just it shouldn't be the _default_.) However, the same chord fingered as 1234 without any bar _does_ make sense as a beginner option.

Comment: @leftaroundabout Thumb around the neck? How? A pinky barre on the 4th fret covering the A shape with the index finger on the second fret A string can be easily played with the thumb where it should be, in the middle of the neck. Not only that but it encourages doing a barre with the 1st finger because it is natural to do so. Your fingering is also sound, of course. Honestly, I can’t even play the chord I described with the thumb over the neck, something i never encourage BTW.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, in a nutshell. But no, not a nice open chord like E (022100), if you're in standard tuning.

B7 has its own non-bar opportunities (see Tim's comment). But I'm going to just stick to B major chords with standard tuning, since that is the original question.

Here are four possibilities; some are easier than others:

[image]
[image]

Use 1, 2, 3 fingers or 2, 3, 4
[image]

[image]

If you are willing to bar a little, there are more too, like xx9877.

These aren't the only ones out there, but hopefully are a good start. Feel free to comment if you'd like more.

Comment: I'd add a B power chord to the mix: x244xxx - easy to play, and easily replaces B major in a lot of situations